# There + verb construction

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence grammatical for example:

"When you set some specific rule in the (computer) program for example, there emerges a specific pattern, which is not unlike a fractal."

Comment: Yes: it's grammatical. "There emerges a specific pattern" is called a 'presentational' clause (not to be confused with an existential clause, as in "There is a fly in my soup").

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is saying that the *pattern* is the thing that *emerges*. As noted by BillJ in the comments, it's a **presentational** form, which looks like an existential form ("there is a specific pattern"), and it replaces a subject-verb form with an apparent subject-verb-object, the subject being the pronoun *there*.

To make a presentational form, you just use the same structure as the existential form, but replace the verb *to be* with the verb you want to use.

> There is a specific pattern

That is the existential form. The presentational form equivalent, using the verb *to emerge*, is:

> There emerges a specific pattern

Now, unlike the existential form, which is not conventionally capable of being rephrased - "a specific pattern is" not being conventional English at all, the presentational form can be rephrased into a more usual form. That is simply:

> A specific pattern emerges.

You might also see:

> In the garden there grew a tree.
>   In the kitchen boiled a kettle.
>   Off the wall there fell a brick.

Comment: Is there a preferability (or unpreferability) of this usage depending on register or whether you are speaking or writing? And there are no errors in my sentence, correct? The preposition 'in is used with the word 'program'?